# NSDateComponentsFormatter adds additional hour

Tags: swift, date-formatting, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I found rather strange behavior of NSDateComponentsFormatter - for some time intervals it just adds additional hour to the result.

I assume that for time intervals over 1 year, it could add a "leap hour", but in this case I see that time interval as short as 5 days results to 5 days and one hour.

Consider this Test Case:

```
func testStringFromTimeInterval()
{
    let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.Year, .Month, .WeekOfMonth, .Day, .Hour, .Minute]

    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600) ?? "", "1:00") // Pass
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600*24) ?? "", "1d 0:00") // Pass
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600*24*5) ?? "", "5d 0:00") // Fail: actual "5d 1:00"
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600*24*365) ?? "", "1y 0m 0w 0d 0:00") // Pass
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval((3600*24*365)+60) ?? "", "1y 0m 0w 0d 0:01") // Pass
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval((3600*24*365)+3600) ?? "", "1y 0m 0w 0d 1:00") // Pass
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval((3600*24*365)+(3600*24)) ?? "", "1y 0m 0w 1d 0:00") // Pass
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval((3600*24*365)+(3600*24*5)) ?? "", "1y 0m 0w 5d 0:00") // Fail: actual "1y 0m 0w 5d 1:00"
}
```

Can you help to find a way to avoid adding that 1 hour?

Thanks!

Maris

Comment: Welcome to daylight saving time... It's March and you are probably in Europe. That means you are a about 3-4 days from Daylight saving time change.

Comment: OK, I can understand that, but daylight savings time is relative to current date. Time interval, however, should not be tied to current date. Otherwise, if I assume that I have worked on project 5 days, then at certain moment in time, when I will look at this number, I will see that I have worked on project 5 days and 1 hour. Somehow inconsistent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Daylight saving time change which happens in Europe in a few days.
I am not sure whether this is the expected behavior of the interval formatter (it definitely seems a bit strange). However, as all time zone problems, you can fix it by setting the time zone to a specific GMT timezone. In this case `GMT-00:00` is probably the expected time zone:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Year, .Month, .WeekOfMonth, .Day, .Hour, .Minute]

let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
calendar.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

formatter.calendar = calendar

print(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600)) // "1:00"
print(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600*24)) // "1d 0:00"
print(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600*24*5)) // "5d 0:00"
print(formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(3600*24*365)) // "1y 0m 0w 0d 0:00"
```

Comment: Be warned, this still doesn’t solve the issues with leap years and leap seconds, it only avoids DST. So depending on the current day of the year and the length of your time interval, you can still get wrong results.